# Next13 project deploy on vercel succesfully but it don't deploy on apprunner

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, next.js, devops, vercel

I don't observe any error in my local build, I can only see the warning and this warning is already present in previous successful builds as well. Also I tried to return my last successfully deployed commit but it did fail again. What can ı do in this situation?

nextjs version: 13.3.1
react version: 18.2.0

next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: {
    appDir: true
  }
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

I only see the following deployment log in app runner

```
12-19-2023 01:17:21 AM [AppRunner] Starting to build your application source code.
12-19-2023 01:20:51 AM [AppRunner] Failed to deploy your application source code.
```